# Getting Error from Service

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am new to GWT and I am trying to call the service I created but I am getting the following error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casing? you url-pattern contains TimeSheetTrack in a different case as the url shown in your error message.

Comment: I tried timesheettrack/authentication but the problem still persists.. now that line at the top (not in the xml) is auto generated by GWT. I do not have that anywhere.. Only in xml.

Comment: Add did you add `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("authentication")` to your service interface: `public interface AuthenticationService extends RemoteService`?

Comment: I added the code for the remoteservice, where would I add that line>

Comment: Did not work  but giving you the credit for trying to help me

Comment: Ok, hope you solved your problem. My first line of my previous comment should read: And did you add...Anyway if it still isn't working you might have a second look at the rpc documentation to see if you missed anything: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html